# What's the SmoothHistogram analogue of Histogram[..., BarOrigin -> Left, ...]?

Tags: plotting, histograms

By default, *Mathematica* plots follow the universal convention of making the abscissa (aka *x*) horizontal and the ordinate (aka *y*) vertical.

Some plot types, however, allow one to specify a different convention.  For example, the following produces a histogram with a vertical abscissa and a horizontal ordinate:

```
Histogram[
 BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0]; 
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000]],
 BarOrigin -> Left]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`BarOrigin`, however, is not a valid `SmoothHistogram` option.

What is the `SmoothHistogram` analogue of the `Histogram` expression above?

---

(I am primarily interested in solutions that do not involve rasterizing the plot and rotating the resulting image.)

---

More generally, how does one plot a function such that the abscissa increases, say, in the upwards vertical direction, and the ordinate increases, say, from left to right?

Comment: If no such analogue option exists, a possible workaround is to use `SmoothKernelDistribution`:  `z = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
pdf = Table[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[z], x], {x, -4, 4, 0.01}];
ListPlot[Transpose[{pdf, Table[x, {x, -4, 4, 0.01}]}], Joined -> True]`.

Comment: ...or, use `ParametricPlot[]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`SmoothKernelDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothKernelDistribution) and [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot). First the distribution:

```
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution @ BlockRandom[
    SeedRandom[0];
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1],1000]
];
```

Then, use [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot) to visualize:

```
ContourPlot[PDF[dist, y] == x, {x, 0, .5}, {y, -3.5, 5}, Frame->False, Axes->True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also post-process `SmoothHistogram` output using `ReflectionTransform`:

```
reflectF = Graphics[#[[1]] /. ll : (_Line | _Polygon) :> 
     GeometricTransformation[ll, ReflectionTransform[{1, -1}]], 
    Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> GoldenRatio] &;

SmoothHistogram[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[0];
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {3, 1000}]], 
   PlotStyle -> Thick, Filling -> Bottom] // reflectF
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]