# Alternative Representation for Energy Levels and Energy Level Density (II)

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, eigenvalues

Following [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/299738/84456), I want a graph that must look like this (*the lower image is taken from the Wikipedia page for the [Microcanonocal Ensemble-->> Quantum Mechanical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble)*),

[image]

The code for solving Schrodinger's equation:

```
a0 = 0.02; a1 = 0.64; L = 10;
U[x_] := a0*x^4 - a1*x^2 + a1^2/(4 a0)
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-1/2 Laplacian[u[x], {x}] + U[x]*u[x], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, True]}, u[x], {x, -L, L}, 25, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" \
-> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}}];
```

> **How do we plot the graphs showing level density as shown in the above figure?**

N.B.

The author used Python to plot the graph shared above. Please see the [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ensemble_quantum_1DOF_canonical.png).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`ColorFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) to plot the wavefunction densities:

```
numEig = 25;
Show[Plot[U[x], {x, -2 L/3, 2 L/3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  AspectRatio -> 1.2, PlotHighlighting -> None], 
 Table[Plot[{vals[[i]]}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Opacity[2 funs[[i]][x]^2, Blue]],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotHighlighting -> None], {i, 1, 
   numEig}]]
```

[image]

As presented in the previous answer, use [`SmoothHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html) for the density of states. To rotate the plot, see [#145789](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145789/whats-the-smoothhistogram-analogue-of-histogram-barorigin-left).

```
SmoothHistogram[vals, 0.1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Domen for this quick response. the first graph is absolutely beautiful. However, I believe, the second graph is not correct. The adjacent graph in the Wikipedia page is a probability graph with inverted axes, i.e. the x-axis shows the state probability while y shows its position on the double well as a function of energy.

Comment: Please see this Python code for the above Wikipedia graph : https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ensemble_quantum_1DOF_canonical.png

Comment: @user444, the plot in your question shows just the density of states, $g(E)$, and that is shown on my plot . The plot in the link you've pasted now shows a canonical ensemble, where you weight the states by the Boltzmann factor to get $\rho(E) = g(E) e^{-\beta E}$. So the two plots are different.

Comment: For the canonical ensemble, you could probably use something like `β = 1/10;
SmoothHistogram[WeightedData[vals, Exp[-β vals]], 0.1]`.

Comment: Thank you @Domen, for you kind help.